# lineTo() method in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I am trying to draw a grid using two **for loops**, one for drawing 10 vertical lines, and another for 10 horizontal ones. Like this:

```
for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
  context.moveTo(0,i*b/10);
  context.lineTo(a,i*b/10);
  context.stroke();
}
```

So the lines drawn are different widthes, blurry..I read adding 0.5 in both moveTo() and lineTo() methods but that does not work either. There is no proportional way of achieving all 10 lines being the same.
First, why is so and what could I do?

---

That is really weird. I had tested all you wrote here and the results were the same. Now I desperately opened  firefox and there everything looks perfect. So it is about chrome only then.

Comment: [Looks fine for me on Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/JWMFz/).

Comment: Can you send more code block so I can test it out for myself and see what you're seeing?

Comment: The fiddle of @bfavaretto looks fine for me too on latest Chrome/FF/Sf on Mac OS 10.8.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line before you start drawing

```
context.translate(0.5, 0.5);
```

and the lines will be razor sharp provided you use integer numbers for the positions.

Specifically in the code you provide:

```
context.translate(0.5, 0.5);
....
context.moveTo(0, (i * b / 10)|0); /// y is rounded to integer
```

or instead of translating:

```
context.moveTo(0.5, (i * b / 10)|0);
```

With canvas the center of a pixel is not on an absolute pixel on screen. Therefor you need to offset it half a pixel to align it with the actual pixel or the pixel will get sub-pixeled which result in an anti-aliased line.

You could just as well add 0.5 to each position instead of doing a translate, but the translate is simpler. Just translate back after the grid is done.

[image: demo snapshot]
<sup>Snapshot from demo</sup>

You also have a second issue in your code: you are stroking the line then continue to add to the same Path which will accumulate *all* the lines added previously and reduce performance.

In the same way as there is also no need to use `beginPath()` for each lines if all the lines will have the same characteristics (color, thickness etc.) you don't need to stroke each line either.

Just add all the lines with `moveTo` and `lineTo` to the Path (`moveTo` will make sure the lines aren't connected) and when the loops are finished then do a common `stroke()`.

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/sGAKV/)**

```
/// translate 0.5
ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);

/// create grid
ctx.beginPath();

/// add all grid lines to Path
for(;pos < width; pos += step) {
    ctx.moveTo(pos, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(pos, height);
    ctx.moveTo(0, pos);
    ctx.lineTo(width, pos);
}

/// common stroke = higher performance
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1):

The blurryness is anti-aliasing  and can partially be avoided specifying drawing positions in whole integers.

[image]

Also, If you draw with lineWidth=.5 and specify a .5 drawing offset, you will have clearer lines.

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4gduD/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var w=canvas.width;
    var h=canvas.height;


    drawGrid("black", 20,20);


    function drawGrid(color, stepx, stepy) {
       ctx.save()

       ctx.strokeStyle = color;
       ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
       ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

       for (var i = stepx + 0.5; i < w; i += stepx) {
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
         ctx.lineTo(i, h);
         ctx.stroke();
       }

       for (var i = stepy + 0.5; i < h; i += stepy) {
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(0, i);
         ctx.lineTo(w, i);
         ctx.stroke();
       }

       ctx.restore();
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```