# Canvas nasty border render

Tags: canvas, border

I have an issue i can't figure out, and it's the first time i see it : i make a grid with canvas, i put 1px black border with globalAlpha set to 1, and my borders rendering with 2px width, and with a light transparency. I never had this trouble with canvas, and i tested it with chrome and firefox, same result.

Here the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EXE4K/

Code :

```
var size = 10, case_size = 18, canvas_size = 180, ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();

for(var i = 0; i <= size; i++) {

    var d = i * case_size;

    ctx.moveTo(0, d);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas_size, d);

   ctx.moveTo(d, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(d, canvas_size);

}

ctx.closePath();

ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';

ctx.stroke();
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: `ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);` before you start to draw: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/EXE4K/1/

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why need I to do this ? It should be working at it's initial scale, no ?

Comment: For some reason canvas default to draw pixels offset half a pixel so we need to compensate for it by moving them 0.5 pixel so a pixel overlap a real pixel exactly. Otherwise the two "half" pixels will be sub-pixeled which result in the two gray-toned pixels that you see (as we can't really draw half pixel on a screen).

Comment: well i never figured out... Thanks dude.

Comment: possible duplicate of [lineTo() method in a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748001/lineto-method-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 2):

This same transparency problem has happened to me too.

But, this is fixable just by asking the program to ctx.stroke(); *twice*. The finishing code will look like:

```
var size = 10, case_size = 18, canvas_size = 180, ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
for(var i = 0; i <= size; i++) {

var d = i * case_size;

ctx.moveTo(0, d);
ctx.lineTo(canvas_size, d);

ctx.moveTo(d, 0);
ctx.lineTo(d, canvas_size);

}

ctx.closePath();

ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.stroke();
```

**I hope this helped!**